# Advice needed on DocuSign e-sign (python)

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Programmatically create envelops containing 2 documents.
2. end clients do not need logins to Sign the envelop / documents.
3. I have opted for JWT Authentication method based on the DocuSign documentation.

Ref: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

Do I need to do the "Request Application Consent"? How does it work?

What do I need to do to achieve e-sign for my application users (anonymous users)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, consent is required for JWT. It is only required once.
Your anonymous users can sign documents in your app without having to log in, but the app, to make API calls, would have to authenticate to DocuSign. JWT allows the app to authenticate on behalf of some system user that would be the sender of all these envelopes.

Suggestion: start with [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart), and see how the Python code works. That would be a good way to learn and start building code in Python and you can even use JWT. Quickstart configures it all for you automatically.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I have previously tried the Quickstart, the authorization code grant flow seems to be working fine but when i try the JWT flow its returning errors.

Comment: what error do you get? did you use the same code you got from quickstart for JWT?

Comment: I have used JWT grant and got a consent, do i need to do the consent for each end user to sign a document? If it is not needed. Can you tell me if there is a expiration for this consent! I have received a "code" & "state" to my call back url. Can i use the same code for as long as possible?

Comment: consent is only required once.
Code is part of Auth Code Grant, not JWT and it's very short lived.
The access token in JWT is for 8 hours.

Comment: After getting the consent, when i call "api_client.request_jwt_user_token" i still get the consent required error. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: did you use both signature and impersonation scopes? for the consent? did you see to things in the list of things the app can do ?

Comment: Also, you have to make sure you use the same account/user for consent that you used when you make the api_client.request_jwt_user_token. That call has a GUID for the userID which must be the same one you used for consent.